# In Laravel 8, how do I get the url of a request when unit testing?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I want to write a unit test in Laravel 8 to test a `POST` request that creates a new entity. In that request, a `job_id` is created and the url has that `job_id` appended. I wish to retrieve that `job_id`. How do I do that?

For example,

```php
$route = route( 'job.store', $payload );
$response = $this->followingRedirects()->post( $route );
```

The `$response` should redirect to something like `http://localhost:9080/sales/job/J00561`. I want to get the url so I can get `job_id`, being `J00561`.

How do I do that?

Comment: try `$response->headers->get('Location')`

Comment: I don't have `Location` in my headers. I have `content-type`, `cache-control`, `date`, and `set-cookie`.

Comment: It's because you use followRedirects - and your response is NOT redirect

Comment: @Raza could you add more details as it is not clear how do you do this ? Can you add the controller method so I can create a test for you ?

Answer (score 0):

For this case, because it is not an API and you cannot get a created job ID from the response, I suggest the following:

```php
// create
$createResponse = $this->post(route('job.store', $payload))
    ->assertSuccessful();

// get created job by params
$job = Job::where($payload)->find();

// check creation
$this->assertNotNull($job);

// assert redirect
$createResponse->assertRedirect($showRoute = route('job.show', $jobId));
$this->get($showRoute)->assertSuccessful();
```

Here is another way: parse the header's `Location` for `jobId`, but in my opinion it's a wrong way:

```php
$response = $this->post(route('job.store', $payload))
   ->assertSucceful();

$params = explode('/', parse_url($response->headers->get('Location'))['path']);

$jobId = array_pop($params);
$response->assertRedirect($showRoute = route('job.show', $jobId));
$this->get($showRoute)->assertSuccessful();
```

Comment: Please add some explanations instead of a code-only answer.

Comment: @endo64 What i can explain here? Pls suggest your edit, i really cannot imagine what i can write about this code.

Comment: I don't have the `$jobId` variable, I need the redirected url to get the jobId in the uri.